# How can I calculate blocks per grid?

Tags: cuda

Suppose I have a GPU that allows the `MAX_THREAD` number of threads per block.

Also, suppose it allows the `MAX_BLOCK_DIM` number of blocks per grid on each grid dimension of x, y, and z.

If `MAX_THREAD` = 1024, and if `dim3 threads_per_block` is set to [32, 8, 4], as 32*8*4=1024, how can I calculate each dimension of `dim3 blocks_per_grid` so that I can launch a kernel like the following?

```
my_kernel<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(... ... ...);
```

For example,

```
dim3 threads_per_block(x, y, z);
dim3 blocks_per_grid(xx, yy, zz);
```

Can I calculate the values of `xx`, `yy`, and `zz` from `x`, `y`, and `z`, respectively?

If not, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, this question makes no sense. The dimensions of a grid don't exist in isolation. They depend on the size of the calculation space and the structure of the kernel you are running. There is no single answer to this question as written (even after the mathematical error was corrected)

Comment: No it doesn't and this is at the heart of your lack of understanding of the whole CUDA execution model and how multidimensional arrays are stored in memory in C like languages. I can't make you understand things, I can only answer sensible questions and this isn't one of those (even after your edit), I am sorry

Comment: Normally you will have some kind of problem size `X`, `Y`, `Z` and then calculate e.g. `xx = (X + x - 1) / x;` (ceiling division). This does not factor in your `MAX_BLOCK_DIM` (which should be named `MAX_GRID_DIM` to avoid confusion). This maximum is much bigger for the x-dimension than or y and z. So if one of your problem dimensions is expected to be especially big, it should be placed in the x-dimension. If multiple of them could go above 65535, you should manually fold them into the x dimension which is capped at (2^31) - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with defining your grid dimensions. This depends on what you are doing. Let's say you have an image with dimensions 1024x768 and you do a pixel-wise computation. Then your grid would naturally be `dim3(1024, 768, 1)`. If a you have a couple of frames from a video, it might be `dim3(width, height, frames)`.

Your block dimensions are dictated by your kernel. If you have no specific need, I advise against using very large blocks such as 1024. This can lead to inefficient utilization because synchronization points such as `__syncthreads()` or the end of a kernel result in comparatibly many threads waiting for a few stragglers. When in doubt, stick with something small such as 128x1x1 or 16x16x1.

Given this, you can calculate the blocks.

```cpp
dim3 grid(1024, 768, 1);
dim3 blockdim(16, 16, 1);
dim3 blocks((grid.x + blockdim.x - 1) / blockdim.x,
            (grid.y + blockdim.y - 1) / blockdim.y,
            (grid.z + blockdim.z - 1) / blockdim.z);
```

This computation is a division rounding up. This ensures that enough blocks are launched when the grid dimensions are not divisible by the block dimensions. The downside is that now you may launch more threads than needed. Effectively your grid gets padded to a multiple of the block dimension. There are multiple ways to cope with this, such as ensuring that array dimensions are always a multiple of 16. The simplest approach, however, is to simply check for out-of-range.

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(int xdim, int ydim, int zdim)
{
    int x_idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y_idx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z_idx = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    if(x_idx < xdim && y_idx < ydim && z_idx < zdim) {
        do_something();
    }
}
```

Normally you can skip the checks in Y and Z dimension if the block dimensions along those axes are 1.

Another approach would be to start only as many threads as can concurrently run on the GPU and then make a loop inside the kernel. This has the benefit of reducing the proportion of the launch overhead compared to the actual work for large grids since all the index computations only need to be done once and more optimizations become possible by pulling parts of the computation out of the loop body.

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(int xdim, int ydim, int zdim)
{
    int x_start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y_start = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int z_start = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    int x_stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int y_stride = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;
    int z_stride = gridDim.z * blockDim.z;
    for(int z_idx = z_start; z_idx < zdim; z_idx += z_stride)
        for(int y_idx = y_start; y_idx < ydim; y_idx += y_stride)
            for(int x_idx = x_start; x_idx < xdim; x_idx += x_stride)
                do_something();
}
```